# Achieving 'noperspective' interpolation in shader profile ps_4_0_level_9_*

Tags: shader, hlsl, direct3d11

I'm trying to do texture mapping without perspective correction while targeting shader profile `ps_4_0_level_9_*`, but the HLSL compiler won't support the `noperspective` interpolation modifier unless I target `ps_4_0`. It appears that the `SV_Position` semantic implies `noperspective`, but I haven't been able to find another semantic that would imply it and that I could use for my UV coordinates. My understanding is that in Direct3D 9, one could use `POSITION[0-9]` and/or `VPOS` to have multiple `noperspective` attributes, but those don't seem to have an effect in my case. Is there an alternate trick for `ps_4_0_level_9_*`?

```c
struct Vertex
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VSToPS
{
    /*noperspective*/ float2 uv : POSITION;
};

Texture2D Texture;

SamplerState Sampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

VSToPS VSMain(
    Vertex vertex,
    out float4 position : SV_Position) // Not needed by PS
{
    position = vertex.position;

    VSToPS output;
    output.uv = vertex.uv;
    return output;
}

float4 PSMain(VSToPS input) : SV_Target
{
    return Texture.Sample(Sampler, input.uv);
}
```